# Download most recent file on sftp of each extension type (PowerShell)

Tags: powershell, sftp, winscp, winscp-net

I have a WinSCP PowerShell script that downloads the most recent file on the server. I'd like to adapt it to download the most recent file of every file type on the server.

Bonus points for naming each file with the extension of the file as the `filename.txt` (`example.al` -> `al.txt`). Here's my code:

```
try
{
    # Connect
    $session.Open($sessionOptions)

    # Get list of files in the directory
    $directoryInfo = $session.ListDirectory($remotePath)

    # Select the most recent file
    $latest =
        $directoryInfo.Files |
        Where-Object { -Not $_.IsDirectory } |
        Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending |
        Select-Object -First 1

    $extension = [System.IO.Path]::GetExtension($latest.Name)
    "GetExtension('{0}') returns '{1}'" -f $fileName, $extension

    # Any file at all?
    if ($latest -eq $Null)
    {
        Write-Host "No file found"
        exit 1
    }

    # Download the selected file
    $session.GetFiles($session.EscapeFileMask($remotePath + $latest.Name), $localPath + $extension).Check()
```

Right now it saves the file as `.extension`, what I'd like is to save it as `extension.txt`.

Thanks!

EDIT:

Tried this code and it downloaded every file on the server:

```
$session = New-Object WinSCP.Session

try
{
    # Connect
    $session.Open($sessionOptions)

    # Get list of files in the directory
    $directoryInfo = $session.ListDirectory($remotePath)

    # Select the most recent file
    $latest = $directoryInfo.Files |
        Where-Object { -Not $_.IsDirectory } | 
        Group-Object Extension | 
        ForEach-Object { 
            $_.Group | Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending | Select -First 1
            $session.GetFiles($session.EscapeFileMask($remotePath + $_.Name), $localPath).Check()
    }

    $extension = [System.IO.Path]::GetExtension($latest.Name)
    "GetExtension('{0}') returns '{1}'" -f $fileName, $extension

    # Any file at all?
    if ($latest -eq $Null)
    {
        Write-Host "No file found"
        exit 1
    }

    # Download the selected file
}
finally
{
    # Disconnect, clean up
    $session.Dispose()
}
```

Comment: In your final code, you have to call the `GetFiles` in a separate statement `$latest | ForEachObject` **after** the statement that assigns the `$latest` variable.

Answer (score 1):

The first part is easy with `Group-Object`. Use that to group by extension and pull to right one out of each group.

```
$latest = $directoryInfo.Files |
    Where-Object { -Not $_.IsDirectory } | 
    Group-Object { [System.IO.Path]::GetExtension($_.Name) } | 
    ForEach-Object{ 
        $_.Group | Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending | Select -First 1
    }
```

Next we process each extension king and download. You could do this in the same loop but I have it in a separate one. The *does not* account for the separate extensions yet.

```
$latest | ForEach-Object{
    $session.GetFiles($session.EscapeFileMask($remotePath + $_.Name), $localPath + $extension).Check()
}
```

I'm a little fuzzy on what you want with extension piece but for that we need to the extension logic in the loop as well.

```
$latest | ForEach-Object{
    $extension = ([System.IO.Path]::GetExtension($_.Name)).Trim(".")
    $session.GetFiles($session.EscapeFileMask($remotePath + $_.Name), "$localPath\$extension.txt" ).Check()
}
```

Comment: This created a new folder in $localpath with the name $extension and downloaded every file on the server into it. (See my original edit)

Comment: Ok I got the files going directly into the $localpath but its still grabbing every single file

Comment: There's no `Extension` property in the [`RemoteFileInfo` class](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_remotefileinfo). I've corrected the `Group-Object` clause.